# Form not working on Access Denied redirection in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a Rails 4 web application, using Devise and CanCanCan.

When a user first signs up to create an account, they are redirected to a subscription page where they enter in credit card details, etc.

> User Creation -> Subscription Creation = Form works

This is working absolutely perfectly and once they enter in their subscription information, a permission change is made on their account and they can then access a new part of the site. All good.

Now the issue I am having is, if a user signs up, then tries to access this new part of the site without subscribing, I redirect them to the subscription page. However when I do this, the form just doesn't work. They hit submit and nothing happens.

> User Creation -> Tries to access resource, gets redirected to
>   Subscription Creation = Form doesn't work

Here is the code I am using to perform the redirection:

```
application_controller.rb    

def access_denied(exception)
        redirect_to(new_subscription_path, alert: exception.message + " Please subscribe.")
    end
```

The strange thing is that I am using the exact same code to redirect when they first create a user account. This is shown here:

```
registrations_controller.rb

    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        new_subscription_path
    end
```

Here is the code for the subscription controller:

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController

    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def new
        @subscription = Subscription.new
    end

    def create
        @subscription = Subscription.new(subscription_params)
        @user = current_user
        @subscription.user_id = current_user.id
        if @subscription.save_with_payment
            redirect_to success_path, :notice => "Thank you for subscribing!"
            if current_user.role = "guest"
                User.update(current_user.id, role: "read")
            end
            UserMailer.subscription_welcome_email(@user).deliver
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

    def show
        @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id])
    end

    def destroy
        @subscription = Subscription.find_by(user_id: current_user.id)
        User.update(current_user.id, role: "guest")
        unless @subscription.stripe_customer_id.nil?
            customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@subscription.stripe_customer_id)
            customer.subscriptions.retrieve(customer.subscriptions.first.id).delete
        end
        @user = current_user
        UserMailer.subscription_destroy_email(@user).deliver
        @subscription.destroy

    rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
        logger.error "Stripe Error: " + e.message
        errors.add :base, "Unable to cancel your subscription. #{e.message}."
        false
    end


    def subscription_params
        params.require(:subscription).permit(:stripe_card_token, :last_4_digits, :plan, :expiry_month, :expiry_year)
    end


end
```

Form code:

```
<div class='panel panel-default'>

    <div class='panel-heading'>
        <h2>Subscribe</h2>
    </div>

    <div class='panel-body'>

        <%= semantic_form_for @subscription, :html => {:class => 'main-form'} do |f| %>

        <font color=red><b><%= f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys %></b></font>

        <%= f.hidden_field :stripe_card_token %>

        <div id='stripe_error' class="alert alert-info" style='display:none'>
        </div>


        <span class="help-block">Nothing is billed to your card for 7 days. <b>Guaranteed. </b>
            <br>If you choose to continue after 7 days, only then will you be billed.</span>

              <div class='form-group'>
                  <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %><%= image_tag "welcome/checkout/amex.png", alt: "American Express", class: "credit-card-image" %><%= image_tag "welcome/checkout/mastercard.png", alt: "Mastercard", class: "credit-card-image" %><%= image_tag "welcome/checkout/visa.png", alt: "Visa", class: "credit-card-image" %>
                  <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil, class: 'form-control input-box', :placeholder => 'Credit Card Number' %>
              </div>

        <div class='row'>

            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <%= label_tag :card_code, "Security Code on Card (CVC)" %><%= image_tag "welcome/checkout/credit.png", alt: "Credit Card Image", class: "credit-card-image" %>
                <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil, class: 'form-control input-box', :placeholder => 'Security Code on Card (CVC)' %>

              </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <%= label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration" %><br>
                <%= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month", class: 'expiration'} %>
                <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year+1, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year", class: 'expiration'} %>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

<div id="stripe_error">
  <noscript>JavaScript is not enabled and is required for this form. First enable it in your web browser settings.</noscript>
</div>

            <div>
                <%= f.submit "Subscribe", class: 'btn standard-button' %>
            </div>


        <% end %>
    </div>

</div>
```

Can anyone assist? Let me know if any extra code is required. Thanks

**EDIT: Just to make things weird, this error is only happening when I hit a link in my navigation that is new_subscription_path .. the access denied works fine if I type in manually the URL of the permissioned resource. Could there be something wrong with the path I am using in the header? Do I need to pass something specific into it? I've also tried to check if it was JavaScript by adding in a console log, but nothing comes through, so I don't think this is an issue, despite it feeling like a JS issue.**

Comment: What is in the log, can you post the controller code and view code for the subscriptions

Comment: Hey @japed code added.

Logs say absolutely nothing unfortunately

Comment: What do you see in the console.log in developer tools when submitting the form - sounds like it's javascript related.

Comment: Nothing in there mate :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabled Turbolinks solved this problem

Answer (score 0):

You should check you javascript. Clearly it blocks form from submission. I've looked at your previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26456208/subscription-not-creating-on-custom-stripe-form-but-is-creating-subscription-on/26492371#26492371) and it looks like your `handleStripeResponse` handler always goes into `else` condition block not submitting form as the result. My bet is that `$('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content')` is undefined after your redirection.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Any reason why it works with the first path described, but not the other?

Comment: Ok I added in a log to console in the else condition to check, and it doesn't seem to be triggering, so not sure what else to do. It does feel like a JS issue though

Comment: @bnussey have you tried commenting out your JS related code?

Comment: What part of it? It doesn't make sense to me that the JS works as per normal in the first path, and not the other.. Shouldn't it not  work in both?

Comment: ok have worked out its Turbolinks doing the damage. Cause of that the jQuery library isn't being loaded